# Slash removed from URL when resolving page after changing site to ssl secure

Tags: apache, ssl

I recently made one of my websites SSL-secure. Since then I have noticed that if I paste a URL of one of the pages on the website into a browser URL bar, when the page tries to resolve, the URL gets mangled and the page is not found.  What it always appears to do is remove the slash after the domain and the following directory, so

waynecbent.com/html/somefile.html

becomes:

waynecbent.comhtml/somefile.html

At first I thought this was something my browser was doing, but since then I have discovered this occurs on different browsers on different platforms.

I contacted my domain provider (Namecheap) but they said it is a problem with the host.

My configuration for the site is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.waynecbent.com
  DocumentRoot /home/<redacted>/public_html
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/home/<redacted>/ssl/<redacted>.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/<redacted>/ssl/<redacted>.pem"
  SSLCACertificateFile "/home/<redacted>/ssl/<redacted>_bundle"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName waynecbent.com
  DocumentRoot /home/<redacted>/public_html
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/home/<redacted>/ssl/<redacted>.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/<redacted>/ssl/<redacted>.pem"
  SSLCACertificateFile "/home/<redacted>/ssl/<redacted>_bundle"
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: looks like a bad rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain registrar should have nothing to do with this issue. They send requests to the domain waynecbent.com to your hoster, which then handles the request. That action occurs correctly I believe based on your http headers.

This issue is almost certainly caused by a defective mod_rewrite rule, so you have to paste in all your htaccess or apache config rewrite rules to solve the issue.

If you have no rewrite rules, then your hoster has messed up something with the ssl handling, that would be my last guess however.

A request to the url is 302 redirected to the bad url, which means there's a rewrite going on somewhere on your server, which is ubuntu with apache 2.2.22, so you can see the request hit your server, and was redirected to that non existent url.

Answer (score 2):

Very closely related to Lizardx's solution, I had a `Redirect` directive that was not written properly:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName waynecbent.com
  Redirect "/" "https://waynecbent.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

I needed to add a trailing slash after the domain:

```
Redirect "/" "https://waynecbent.com/"
```

I'm going to accept Lizardx's very informative answer for being the catalyst and recognizing there was a redirect happening.

EDIT:

Referring to Lizardx's comment below, it appears you can use the `Redirect` directive to do a permanent redirect the following ways:

```
Redirect 301 "/" "https://example.com/"
Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"
```

I also note that some online documentation I have read regarding using the `Redirect` directive for redirecting non-ssl urls to ssl give examples that do not include the trailing slash.  However, as this thread has revealed, this caused a problem in my case.

Comment: You want to fix your redirect to be a 301 redirect, otherwise google etc keeps first trying the old url, http://.. 301 is permanent, 302 is temporary, I never use that short redirect format so I'm not sure what the right syntax is there to force a 301.